# how to make customized menu for every user using dynamic master page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

My problem is almost the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135933/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-modify-role-permissions-and-also-generate-the-appr)

But I want to use a dynamic master page, is it possible?

I want to apply restrictions to the menu for every user dynamically.
I'm new to asp.net, all I know is that there is a way to work with master pages dynamically but I don't know how!

Update:

Briefly, I want to change my menu items depending on the identity of the users, and I want to know whether it is possible to achieve this by changing the content of the master page (which holds the menu) dynamically or not.

By the way, I've made everything with HTML.
I haven't used asp tags so far. Like I said earlier I'm new to asp.net.

Comment: Describe what you mean by "dynamically". What's going to be dynamic about it?

Comment: @mason I updated my question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing here is code I can provide to you (the name of main menu control
is: Menu, so here is the master page code:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DispMenues();
        }


 private void DispMenues()
        {
            Menu.Items.Clear();
            MenuItem mnuHome = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspHome&nbsp&nbsp", "Home");
            mnuHome.NavigateUrl = "~/index.aspx";
            Menu.Items.Add(mnuHome);

            if (Session["urole"] != null)
                switch (Session["urole"].ToString())
                {
                    case "supadmin":
                        SupAdmMenu();
                        break;
                    case "controller":
                        ContMenu();
                        break;
                    case "admin":
                        AdmMenu();
                        break;
                    case "supervisor":
                        SupMenu();
                        break;
                    case "deo":
                        DEOMenu();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
                        break;
                }

            MenuItem mnuTools = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspTools&nbsp&nbsp", "Tools");
            mnuTools.NavigateUrl = "~/tools.aspx";
            Menu.Items.Add(mnuTools);
        }

        #region AllMenues
        private void SupAdmMenu()
        {
            DataFeeding(); Manage();
            EditData(); Reports();
        }

        private void ContMenu()
        {
            DataFeeding(); Manage();
            EditData(); Reports();
        }

        private void AdmMenu()
        {
            DataFeeding(); EditData();
            Reports();
        }

        private void SupMenu()
        {
            DataFeeding(); EditData();
            Reports();
        }

        private void DEOMenu()
        {
            DataFeeding(); EditData();
        }
        // Actual Menu Functions
        private void DataFeeding()
        {
            // Main menu data feeding
            MenuItem mnuMainDataFeed = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspData Feeding&nbsp&nbsp", "DataFeeding");

            // Add first level menus under Data Feeding main menu
            MenuItem mnuMlkProd = new MenuItem("Milk Production", "MilkProduction");
            mnuMlkProd.NavigateUrl = "~/mprodentry.aspx";

            MenuItem mnuPedigree = new MenuItem("Pedigree", "Pedigree");
            mnuPedigree.NavigateUrl = "~/pedigentry.aspx";

            MenuItem mnuPedigreeExt = new MenuItem("External Animal", "External Animal");
            mnuPedigreeExt.NavigateUrl = "~/pedigextrnlentry.aspx";

            MenuItem mnuDisposalData = new MenuItem("Disposal", "Disposal");
            mnuDisposalData.NavigateUrl = "~/dispentry.aspx";

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuMlkProd);
            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuPedigree);
            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuPedigreeExt);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Feed
            MenuItem mnuFeedingData = new MenuItem("Feeding", "Feeding");
            MenuItem mnuYoungAnimFeed = new MenuItem("Young Animal", "YoungAnimal");
            mnuYoungAnimFeed.NavigateUrl = "~/calfdngentry.aspx";
            mnuFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuYoungAnimFeed);

            MenuItem mnuLactDryAnim = new MenuItem("Lactating/Dry Animal", "LactDryAnim");
            mnuLactDryAnim.NavigateUrl = "~/lctdryentry.aspx";
            mnuFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuLactDryAnim);

            MenuItem mnuBullsFeed = new MenuItem("Bulls", "Bulls");
            mnuBullsFeed.NavigateUrl = "~/bullfdentry.aspx";
            mnuFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuBullsFeed);

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuFeedingData);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Breeding and Reproduction
            MenuItem mnuBreedReprod = new MenuItem("Breeding & Reproduction", "BreedReprod");

            MenuItem mnuCalvingRecord = new MenuItem("Calving Record", "CalvingRecord");
            mnuCalvingRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/calvngentry.aspx";
            mnuBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuCalvingRecord);

            MenuItem mnuServiceRecord = new MenuItem("Service Record", "ServiceRecord");
            mnuServiceRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/seviceentry.aspx";
            mnuBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuServiceRecord);

            MenuItem mnuServicePos = new MenuItem("Service Position", "Service Position");
            mnuServicePos.NavigateUrl = "~/servposentry.aspx";
            mnuBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuServicePos);

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuBreedReprod);


            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Diseases
            MenuItem mnuDiseases = new MenuItem("Diseases", "Diseases");
            MenuItem mnuDiseaseData = new MenuItem("Disease Data", "Disease Data");
            mnuDiseaseData.NavigateUrl = "~/disentry.aspx";
            mnuDiseases.ChildItems.Add(mnuDiseaseData);

            MenuItem mnuTreatData = new MenuItem("Treatment Data", "Treatment Data");
            mnuTreatData.NavigateUrl = "~/treatmntentry.aspx";
            mnuDiseases.ChildItems.Add(mnuTreatData);

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuDiseases);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Inventory
            MenuItem mnuInventory = new MenuItem("Inventory", "Inventory");

            MenuItem mnuStock = new MenuItem("Stock", "Stock");
            mnuStock.NavigateUrl = "~/inventstckentry.aspx";
            mnuInventory.ChildItems.Add(mnuStock);

            MenuItem mnuDeadStock = new MenuItem("Dead Stock", "DeadStock");
            mnuDeadStock.NavigateUrl = "~/deadstckentry.aspx";
            mnuInventory.ChildItems.Add(mnuDeadStock);

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuInventory);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Land
            MenuItem mnuLand = new MenuItem("Land", "Land");

            MenuItem mnuLandRecord = new MenuItem("Land Record", "LandRecord");
            mnuLandRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/landrcrdentry.aspx";
            mnuLand.ChildItems.Add(mnuLandRecord);

            MenuItem mnuCultivatatedLand = new MenuItem("Cultivated", "Cultivated");
            mnuCultivatatedLand.NavigateUrl = "~/landcultvtdentry.aspx";
            mnuLand.ChildItems.Add(mnuCultivatatedLand);

            MenuItem mnuCultivationYears = new MenuItem("Cultivation Years", "CultivationYears");
            mnuCultivationYears.NavigateUrl = "~/cultyrsentry.aspx";
            mnuLand.ChildItems.Add(mnuCultivationYears);

            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuLand);

            MenuItem mnuMilkCons = new MenuItem("Milk Consumption", "MilkConsumption");
            mnuMilkCons.NavigateUrl = "~/milkconsmpentry.aspx";
            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuMilkCons);


            // Add last main menu under Feed data menu
            mnuMainDataFeed.ChildItems.Add(mnuDisposalData);

            // Add feeding data main menu to menu bar
            Menu.Items.Add(mnuMainDataFeed);
        }
        private void Manage()
        {
            MenuItem mnuMainMngAll = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspManage&nbsp&nbsp", "Manage");
            string urole = Session["urole"].ToString();

            MenuItem mnuManageLoc = new MenuItem("Manage Location", "ManageLocation");
            // Shared inside Manage Locations
            MenuItem mnuMngProv = new MenuItem("Province", "Province");
            mnuMngProv.NavigateUrl = "~/manageprov.aspx";
            mnuManageLoc.ChildItems.Add(mnuMngProv);

            MenuItem mnuStations = new MenuItem("Stations", "Stations");
            mnuStations.NavigateUrl = "managest.aspx";
            mnuManageLoc.ChildItems.Add(mnuStations);

            MenuItem mnuMngNewAccReqs = new MenuItem("New Accounts", "NewAccounts");
            mnuMngNewAccReqs.NavigateUrl = "approveacc.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mnuMngNewAccReqs);

            MenuItem mnuMngPasswords = new MenuItem("Manage Users", "ManageUsers");
            mnuMngPasswords.NavigateUrl = "~/manageusers.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mnuMngPasswords);

            // Only supervisor has access to Manage Country menu
            if (urole.Equals("supadmin"))
            {
                MenuItem mnuMngCountry = new MenuItem("Country", "Country");
                mnuMngCountry.NavigateUrl = "~/SupAdmSection/managecountry.aspx";
                mnuManageLoc.ChildItems.Add(mnuMngCountry);
            }

            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mnuManageLoc);

            MenuItem mngAnimStatus = new MenuItem("Animal Status", "AnimStatus");
            mngAnimStatus.NavigateUrl = "manageanimst.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngAnimStatus);

            MenuItem mngBulServStatus = new MenuItem("Bull Service", "BullService");
            mngBulServStatus.NavigateUrl = "managebullsrvst.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngBulServStatus);

            MenuItem mngCalfStatus = new MenuItem("Calf Status", "CalfStatus");
            mngCalfStatus.NavigateUrl = "managecalfst.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngCalfStatus);

            MenuItem mngDisCondition = new MenuItem("Disease Condition", "DiseaseCondition");
            mngDisCondition.NavigateUrl = "managediscond.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngDisCondition);

            MenuItem mngDisName = new MenuItem("Disease Name", "DiseaseName");
            mngDisName.NavigateUrl = "managedisnam.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngDisName);

            MenuItem mngDispReason = new MenuItem("Disposal Reason", "DisposalReason");
            mngDispReason.NavigateUrl = "managedisprsn.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngDispReason);

            MenuItem mngFertPos = new MenuItem("Fertility Position", "FertilityPosition");
            mngFertPos.NavigateUrl = "managefertpos.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngFertPos);

            MenuItem mngMlkSaleRate = new MenuItem("Milk Sale Rate", "MilkSaleRate");
            mngMlkSaleRate.NavigateUrl = "managemlkslrt.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngMlkSaleRate);

            MenuItem mngBreed = new MenuItem("Animal Breed", "Animal Breed");
            mngBreed.NavigateUrl = "manageanimbrd.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngBreed);

            MenuItem mngAnimTerm = new MenuItem("Animal Term Name", "ManageTermName");
            mngAnimTerm.NavigateUrl = "manageanmtrm.aspx";
            mnuMainMngAll.ChildItems.Add(mngAnimTerm);


            Menu.Items.Add(mnuMainMngAll);
        }
        private void EditData()
        {
            // Main menu Edit Data
            MenuItem mnuMainEditData = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspEdit Data&nbsp&nbsp", "EditData");

            // Add first level menus under Data Feeding main menu
            MenuItem mnuEdtMlkProd = new MenuItem("Milk Production", "MilkProduction");
            mnuEdtMlkProd.NavigateUrl = "~/editmprod.aspx";

            MenuItem mnuEdtPedigree = new MenuItem("Pedigree", "Pedigree");
            mnuEdtPedigree.NavigateUrl = "~/editpedigdata.aspx";

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtMlkProd);
            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtPedigree);



            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Feed
            MenuItem mnuEdtFeedingData = new MenuItem("Feeding", "Feeding");
            MenuItem mnuEdtYoungAnimFeed = new MenuItem("Young Animal", "YoungAnimal");
            mnuEdtYoungAnimFeed.NavigateUrl = "~/editclfedng.aspx";
            mnuEdtFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtYoungAnimFeed);

            MenuItem mnuEdtLactDryAnim = new MenuItem("Lactating/Dry Animal", "LactDryAnim");
            mnuEdtLactDryAnim.NavigateUrl = "~/editdrylact.aspx";
            mnuEdtFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtLactDryAnim);

            MenuItem mnuEdtBullsFeed = new MenuItem("Bulls", "Bulls");
            mnuEdtBullsFeed.NavigateUrl = "~/editbulsfd.aspx";
            mnuEdtFeedingData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtBullsFeed);

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtFeedingData);


            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Breeding and Reproduction
            MenuItem mnuEdtBreedReprod = new MenuItem("Breeding & Reproduction", "BreedReprod");

            MenuItem mnuEdtCalvingRecord = new MenuItem("Calving Record", "CalvingRecord");
            mnuEdtCalvingRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/editcvngrcrd.aspx";
            mnuEdtBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtCalvingRecord);

            MenuItem mnuEdtServiceRecord = new MenuItem("Service Record", "ServiceRecord");
            mnuEdtServiceRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/editsrvcrcrd.aspx";
            mnuEdtBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtServiceRecord);

            MenuItem mnuEdtServicePos = new MenuItem("Service Position", "Service Position");
            mnuEdtServicePos.NavigateUrl = "~/editservpos.aspx";
            mnuEdtBreedReprod.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtServicePos);

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtBreedReprod);


            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Edit Data > Feeding > Diseases
            MenuItem mnuEdtDiseases = new MenuItem("Diseases", "Diseases");

            MenuItem mnuEdtDiseaseData = new MenuItem("Disease Data", "Disease Data");
            mnuEdtDiseaseData.NavigateUrl = "~/editdis.aspx";
            mnuEdtDiseases.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtDiseaseData);

            MenuItem mnuEdtTreatData = new MenuItem("Treatment Data", "Treatment Data");
            mnuEdtTreatData.NavigateUrl = "~/edittrtmnt.aspx";
            mnuEdtDiseases.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtTreatData);

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtDiseases);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Edit Data > Inventory
            MenuItem mnuEdtStock = new MenuItem("Inventory", "Inventory");

            MenuItem mnuEdtOfficeStock = new MenuItem("Stock", "Stock");
            mnuEdtOfficeStock.NavigateUrl = "~/editinvntstck.aspx";
            mnuEdtStock.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtOfficeStock);

            MenuItem mnuDeadStock = new MenuItem("Dead Stock", "DeadStock");
            mnuDeadStock.NavigateUrl = "~/editdeadstck.aspx";
            mnuEdtStock.ChildItems.Add(mnuDeadStock);

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtStock);

            // Add 2nd/3rd level menus under Data Feeding > Land
            MenuItem mnuEdtLand = new MenuItem("Land", "Land");

            MenuItem mnuEdtLandRecord = new MenuItem("Land Record", "LandRecord");
            mnuEdtLandRecord.NavigateUrl = "~/editlandrcrd.aspx";
            mnuEdtLand.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtLandRecord);

            MenuItem mnuEdtCultand = new MenuItem("Cultivated", "Cultivated");
            mnuEdtCultand.NavigateUrl = "~/editlandcultvtd.aspx";
            mnuEdtLand.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtCultand);

            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtLand);

            // Add menu under Edit Data > Disposal
            MenuItem mnuEdtDispData = new MenuItem("Disposal", "Disposal");
            mnuEdtDispData.NavigateUrl = "~/editdisp.aspx";
            mnuMainEditData.ChildItems.Add(mnuEdtDispData);

            // Add edit data main menu to menu bar
            Menu.Items.Add(mnuMainEditData);
        }
        private void Reports()
        {
            MenuItem mnuReportsMain = new MenuItem("&nbsp&nbspView Report&nbsp&nbsp", "ViewReport");
            mnuReportsMain.NavigateUrl = "~/reportoptions.aspx";
            // Add View Reports main menu
            Menu.Items.Add(mnuReportsMain);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```